# CSV File Formatting

Tags: perl, parsing, csv

I wrote a perl  script to output a text file filled with ip addresses and ports that i scanned into microsoft excel. Now that the data is in excel my boss wants me to organize the file in csv format such as

```
Server, port, protocol, random, random, random
ns1,    25,   tcp,      stuff,  stuff,  stuff
```

Can any one help me with this Please?

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$input = `Cat /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/test11.txt | grep -v 'SYN Stealth'`;
chomp input;
$output =" /cygdrive/c/Users/bpaul/Desktop/194.csv ";
if (! -e "$output")
{
`touch $output`;
}
open (OUTPUTFILE, ">$output") || die "Can't Open file $output";
print OUTPUTFILE "$input\n";
close (OUTPUTFILE);
```

Here is a piece of my file

```
Nmap scan report for 69.25.194.2 Host is up (0.072s latency). Not shown: 9992 filtered ports PORT STATE SERVICE 25/tcp open smtp
80/tcp open http
82/tcp open xfer
443/tcp open
https 4443/tcp closed
pharos 5666/tcp closed
nrpe 8080/tcp closed
http-proxy 9443/tcp closed tungsten-https
```

So far my code took my txt file and outputted it to excel now I need to format the data like this:

Desired Output:

```
Server, port, protocol, random, random, random
ns1,    25,   tcp,      stuff,  stuff,  stuff
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you meant `69.25.194.2` when you said `ns1`.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV_XS qw( );

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ binary => 1, eol => "\n" });

$csv->print(\*STDOUT, [qw(
    Server
    port
    protocol
    random
    random
    random
)]);

my $host = '[unknown]';

while (<>) {
    $host = $1 if /Nmap scan report for (\S+)/;

    my ($port, $protocol) = m{(\d+)/(\w+) (?:open|closed)/
        or next;

    $csv->print(\*STDOUT, [
        $host,
        $port,
        $protocol,
        'stuff',
        'stuff',
        'stuff',
    ]);
}
```

Usage:

```
grep -v 'SYN Stealth' /cygdrive/c/Windows/System32/test11.txt | perl to_csv.pl > /cygdrive/c/Users/bpaul/Desktop/194.csv
```

[Text::CSV_XS](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3a%3aCSV_XS)

**Update**: Replaced hardcoded `ns1` with address of scanned machine.

**Update**: Replaced generic usage with what the OP would use.

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to do it w/o use Text::CSV_XS qw( ); i usually get error messages in cygwin when i try to use this.

Comment: @kingp, What error message? Did you install Text::CSV_XS? (`cpan Text::CSV_XS`)